# facebook connect button to submit a form

Tags: facebook

Is it possible to use the facebook connect button to submit a form?

I have a form in my homepage and I would like to submit it using the facebook connect button (or a submit button if the user is already connected).

I want to prevent reloading the homepage after the user connects.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain you can't do this. Connecting to Facebook is a process that Facebook doesn't let you piggyback your own data on. Most sites handle this by having the user connect with Facebook first, then fill out the form (that's now tied to their Facebook user ID).